# Sitecore Powershell Test-Account -Identity breaks with email as username

Tags: sitecore-commerce, powershell-extensions

I am in need to iterate through a list of emails (that happen to be username in Sitecore CMS) and then remove the users. I would like to have an "if" statement to see if account is present before attempting to remove it.

```ps1
# list of emails, one per line, ex. "user@host.com"
$removeEmails = Get-Content C:\AccountsToRemove.txt     
foreach ($email in $removeEmails) {
  $account = "Storefront\$($email)"
  if (Test-Account -Identity $account)
  {
     $email | Remove-User
     Write-Output "Removed: '$email'"
  }
}
```

But I get PowerShell complaining as follows:

> Test-Account : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "Storefront\user@email.com" to type "Spe.Commands.Security.AccountIdentity". Error: "The name
> 'Storefront\user@email.com' is improperly formatted.

> The name can only contain the following characters: a-z, 0-9, periods, dashes, underscores, backslashes, and spaces.
> Parameter name: name"

How do I overcome this issue?

Thank you for your help in advance!!

**UPDATE:**

I found a thread mentioning that RegEx is too restrictive: [Cannot add a User to a Role where the User name contains the "@" sign using PSE](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/cannot-add-a-user-to-a-role-where-the-user-name-contains-the-sign-using-pse)

Hopefully issue will be resolved in some next version.
Still same issue in Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 6.3.0.17327
Windows PowerShell 5.1
(Sitecore 9.3)

BUT if anyone can think of a workaround... please help!!
and no,

```ps
Get-User -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.Profile.Email -like "user@email.com"} | Remove-User
```

is not viable with over million users - Sitecore CM hangs like crazy. This is based of post here: https://munirhassan.com/2021/03/29/remove-sitecore-users-from-the-core-database/

**NOTE 1 (sitecore domain)**

Was able to add user with email as username after easing restrictions with:

> <setting name="AccountNameValidation" value=".+" />

and running the script (user is in "sitecore" domain: "sitecore\abc@gmail.com")

[image: Remove user with email as username - sitecore domain]

**NOTE 2 (Storefront domain with plus)**

[image: Remove user with email as username - Storefront domain]

**NOTE 3 (Storefront domain no plus)**

[image: Remove user with email as username -Storefront domain no plus]

Comment: Can you add this setting to allow user creation with email? and try example I posted.
<setting name="AccountNameValidation" value=".+" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example from 9.3

```ps
    $removeEmails = @("abc@gmail.com","pqr@gmail.com")
    foreach ($email in $removeEmails) {
        $account = "Storefront\$email"
        if (Test-Account -Identity $account)
        {
           $account | Remove-User
           Write-Output "Removed: $account"
        }
        else
        {
           Write-Output "Not found user: $account"
        }
     }
```

Comment: No, it does not work. Now "Storefront" part is lost.

Comment: And the issue is that it does not like the "@" in the username (this is being an email and all). I believe this is the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: what is your sitecore version?

Comment: 9.3.0 rev. 003498

Comment: I see that you updated code in your question so updating answer with working example from SC 9.3

Comment: try adding user "abc@gmail.com" for "sitecore" domain and run the example code. If you still get the error, share the latest error message.

Comment: It does not let me do it manually, as in general @ is not allowed in a username.

Comment: Was able to add user with email as username after easing restrictions with:  <setting name="AccountNameValidation" value=".+" />   - please see original post with screenshot (worked for "sitecore" domain to remove user).

Comment: that's good. It seems the issue is in C:\AccountsToRemove.txt. Verify it contains valid entries

Comment: No. Same error even if provided directly. Maybe Sitecore Commerce has a similar setting somewhere? Like the one we did for "sitecore" domain: <setting name="AccountNameValidation" value=".+" />

Comment: Ok - it seems like it is something to do not with "@" character but with a "+" sign. See screenshot in original post.

Comment: I believe I am good if this is the case. Thank you so much!